# Не работает XOR

Tags: c++, visual-studio, шифрование

Второй день пытаюсь сделать шифрование Xor'ом, но все никак не получается. Вот мой код. Что у меня не так?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);


int key;
char text[100];
string res;

cout << "Введите текст: " << endl; // ввожу текст
cin >> text;

cout << "Введите ключ: " << endl;
cin >> key; // ввожу ключ


for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) { // подгоняю размер
    res[i] = text[i] ^ key; //само шифрование

}
cout << "Зашифрованный текст: " << res << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что именно не получается? Кроме проверки соответствия длины ключа и сообщения, криминала не вижу. Ну и под `res` память бы выделить

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Ну вот допустим если я введу любое слово и ключ, вылазит ошибка Line:2954, Expression: string subscript out of range

Comment: Я же сказал - память под string нужно выделить

Comment: Для начала расскажите, какую Вы задачу решаете? Какая у Вас длина ключа? Зачем вам тип `string`. И нужно ли Вам одновременно хранить исходную строку и зашифрованную?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov А как выделить динамическое кол во памяти? Я сделал string *res = new string; , но оно выдает ошибку "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи. _Left было (адрес)"

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Длина ключа до 20 символов и пользователь сам их вводит. Нет, одновременно хранить их не нужно. А string.. ну не знаю, просто решил в нем выводить результат. Если это неправильно, напишите, я изменю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже сказали, у тебя строка `res` нулевой длины, т.е. строка есть, а память под симполы не выделено. Прежде чем обратиться в i_тому символу, надо чтоб этот символ был. Т.е. надо проинициализировать строку `res`, например, так:

```
....
char text[100];

cout << "Введите текст: " << endl; // ввожу текст
cin >> text;
string res(test);
...
```

Теперь у тебя строка `res` эта полная копия `text`. Но тут правильно заметили, если тебе не нужно хранить оригинальную строку, то можешь прямое ее и модифицировать вот так:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) { // подгоняю размер
    text[i] = text[i] ^ key; //само шифрование

}
cout << "Зашифрованный текст: " << text << endl;
...
```

Но и тут есть подводные камни. Если ты введешь ключ который совпадает с ASCII кодом символа из строки, то после операции XOR на месте это символа окажется `\0`, что является признаком конца троки. Тогда std::cout распечатает зашифрованную строку только до этого символа и у тебя будет навсегда потерям оригинальный размер строки.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение! @ffk

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string key;
std::string str;

std::cout << "Введите текст: " << std::endl;
std::getline(std::cin, str); // вводим текст. Память выделяется автоматически

std::cout << "Введите ключ: " << std::endl;
std::getline(std::cin, key);  // вводим ключ

int keyIdx = 0;  // текущий индекс байта ключа
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
  str[i] = str[i] ^ key[keyIdx++]; // шифруем строку и смещаем индекс ключа
  if (keyIdx == key.size())  // если достигли конца ключа - начинаем сначала
    keyIdx = 0;
}
std::cout << "Зашифрованный текст: " << str << std::endl;
```

Тип std::string может содержать \0 внутри строки

Comment: И за что минус?

Comment: Спасибо за пример! @Anton Shchyrov

Comment: А завершение шифрования раньше конца строки из за \0 возможно пофиксить?

Comment: @P1NG2WIN Тип `string` этой проблеме не подвержен. Там размер задается отдельно. Проблема актуальна только для `char*`

Comment: Но ты же сам пишешь что он может содержать \0 и вот даже с твоим кодом у меня что-то не получается [ https://imgur.com/a/iAKLs ] + там где английским у меня почему то не вставлялся текст

Comment: @P1NG2WIN Правильно. **Может**. И ни к чему плохому это не приведет. И код работает правильно. То, что консоль не может **отобразить** символы - это не проблема кода. Выводите тогда в консоль не строки, а коды символов

Comment: Спасибо, буду думать @Anton Shchyrov

Comment: Я почитал, что тип string выводит сообщение до первого конца строки. То есть если в итоге в str будет содержатся \0, то оно выведет сообщение до этого символа и шифрование будет неправильным. Вот это я имел ввиду @Anton Shchyrov

Comment: @P1NG2WIN Вы прочитали бред. Выводится вся строка, а вот отображается - что получится [Пример](https://ideone.com/kGNkUH)

Comment: Да, щас проверил, оно просто ставит пробел на месте символа, из которого образовалась \0.  Даже так, все равно получается неправильно и это надо фиксить. Может вы знаете в каком направлении надо гуглить для фикса?

Comment: @P1NG2WIN Я же Вам писал - выводить на консоль символы, которые консоль не может отобразить - глупо. Выводите тогда коды символов